# How to return Primary Key from Insert statement Mysql Java Eclipselink

Tags: java, mysql, rest, jpa, eclipselink

I have a simple namednativequery that generates new PK upon insert for REST web service.

```
Message.java
    @NamedNativeQueries({@NamedNativeQuery( name="Message.send", query="INSERT INTO Leaf.Message (MessageID,Status,Message,Description,SentTime,ipAdd) VALUES\n" +
    "(null,?Status,?Message,NOW()),?ipAdd;")})


AbstractFacade.java

 public void CreateMessage(Message entity,  InetAddress clientIP) {
        try{
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Message.send",entityClass);
        q.setParameter("Status", "send");
        q.setParameter("Message", entity.getMessage());
        q.setParameter("ipAdd",clientIP.hashCode());
        q.executeUpdate();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            String s= ""+e.getMessage().toString();
        }}
```

How do I get the newly created PK?  Is it using SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() ? Because the executeUpdate doesn't return the result? and ResultSet rs = q.getGeneratedKeys(); is not a valid syntax for this.

Comment: Just wondering what is the point of using JPA like if it was JDBC?

Comment: agree with @dic19 . My addition: native insertions in JPA controlled database is very bad concept, violates many rules

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for MySQL, it would be [LAST_INSERT_ID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

However, in your case it would make much more sense to just use [EntityManager::persist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-). For example, have a look at the [Hibernate tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa-test):

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist( new Event( "Our very first event!", new Date() ) );
entityManager.persist( new Event( "A follow up event", new Date() ) );
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

In your case, you would pass an instance of `Message` to the persist method.

After `persist` has returned, you can directly access the identity of the entity by calling `getMessageID`:

```
getEntityManager().persist(message);
System.out.println("Inserted message: " + message.getMessageID());
```